# How to take non alpha characters out of a string and put them back into the string in the same order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to make a Pig Latin translator, but I have an issue with my code where it doesn't work properly when a word such as "hi" or /chair/ is input. This is because I need my code to detect that the input has a non-alpha character, take it out of the string, and put it back in when it's done changing the string. I am struggling to make this, though.

```
  # Pig Latin 11/11/20
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    vowels = ("A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
    message = input("Input text to be translated to Pig 
    Latin\n")
message = message.split()
not_alpha = {}
new_message = []
for word in message:
```

This commented out section is what I tried to solve this problem with, before the word would go through the editing process, it would go through here and remove the non_alpha keys and place them in a dictionary called not_alpha. My thought process was that I would place it in a dictionary with the character as the key, and the index in the string as the value. Then, at the end, I would loop through every letter in word and reconstruct the word with all the non-alpha characters in order.

```
    # for letter in word:
    #     if not letter.isalpha():
    #         not_alpha[letter] = word.index(letter)
    #         word = word
    #     for k in not_alpha.keys():
    #         word.replace(k, "")
    letter_editing = word[0]
    if word.isalpha():
        if letter_editing.upper() in vowels:
            word += "yay"
        else:
            letter_editing = word[0:2]
            if letter_editing.upper() in vowels:
                word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
            else:
                word = word[2:] + word[0:2] + "ay"

    #  for letter in word:
    #     if word.index(letter) in not_alpha.values():
```

Comment: I think you are over complicating the process.  While I don't know your exact rules for pig latin conversion, they are usually something along the lines of:

Answer (score 0):

While I am not positive of all the rules of pig latin you need to apply, from what I see you are only applying two:

1. Rule 1 - First Letter is Consonant - in which case you are moving
   the    first letter to the end of the word and adding ay.
2. Rule 2 - First Letter is Vowel - in which case you are simply adding ay to
   the end of the word.

Given these 2 rules and the following observations:

- The input message is a stream of alphanumeric characters, punctuation characters and white space characters of length L.
- the start of a word within the message is delineated by one or more punctuation or whitespace characters preceding the word.
- the end of a word is delineated by either a punctuation character, a whitespace character or end of message.

You can accomplish the translation as follows:

```
from string import whitespace, punctuation
vowels = 'aeiou'
message = "Oh! my what a beautiful day for the fox to jump the fence!"
output = ""               #The output buffer
temp_buf = ""             #Temp storage for latin add-ons
word_found = False        #Flag to identify a word has been found
cp = 0                    # Character pointer to letter of interest in message

while cp < len(message):
    ch = message[cp]
    if whitespace.find(ch) >= 0 or punctuation.find(ch) >= 0:
        word_found = False
        if temp_buf:
            output += temp_buf
            temp_buf = ""
        output += ch
    else:
        if word_found:
            output += ch
        else:
            word_found = True
            if vowels.find(ch.lower()) >= 0:
                temp_buf = "ay"
                output += ch
            else:
                temp_buf += ch + "ay"
    cp += 1
if temp_buf:
    output += temp_buf
print(output)
```

Comment: I must admit @AKX solution is more elegant and succinct

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement this using the callback form of `re.sub`, where you can have a function determine the replacement for the regular expression match.

```
import re

vowels = "aeiou"


def mangle_word(match):
    word = match.group(0)
    if word[0].lower() in vowels:
        return word + "ay"
    return word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"


message = "Oh! my what a beautiful day for the fox to jump 653 fences!"

print(re.sub("[a-z]+", mangle_word, message, flags=re.I))
```

outputs

```
Ohay! ymay hatway aay eautifulbay ayday orfay hetay oxfay otay umpjay 653 encesfay!
```